# I cant solve my problem with rigging and weights

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, vertex-weights

I tried to connect head with body of my model. But when i tried to setup rigging, smth went wrong with weights. If i rotate neck's bone, head rotates as well but not deformates at all. I have problems only with connected head, other parts of body moves normaly.
P.S. Sorry for my English, hope somebody can help.

Mesh and rig are not connected in file, i leave it to my saver

[image: Neck is not deformating at all]

Comment: Hello please share your file (upload and copy paste the generated URL): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Shared, as you said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason (?) the parent *With Automatic Weights* doesn't work good here, that said what you can do is:

- Apply the scale of your object
- Deactivate the *Deform* option of the eye bones as I suppose you'll parent the eyes meshes later
- Select the neck bone and in the *Bone panel > Bendy Bones > Segments*, choose for example a segmentation of 5, so that the neck will twist nicely
- Select the armature in *Object* mode, shift select the *Character*, switch it to *Weight Paint* mode, in the *N* panel, deactivate the *Advanced > Front Face Only* option in order to paint through, and under *Falloff > Falloff Shape*, choose *Projected*, and weight paint to correct the weight.

Once done it works fine:

[image]

**Edit:** For your second attempt, as I say you need to give some corrections after parenting, for example the neck bone should not influence the head mesh, you need to substract weight here:

[image]

And as you see for some reason the head bone doesn't influence the head mesh, here you need to add weight:

[image]

Comment: I've edited my answer, as I said you need to give some corrections in Weight Paint mode

Comment: Oh god, man, thank you. You saved hours of my life